# Compass sensor not giving the right values

Tags: c, math, 3d, raspberry-pi, compass

I'm now working with the HMC5883L compass sensor from Honeywell, and I cannot figure out how to get the right values. I implemented the X,Y,Z axis in my code and I figured that the formula I'm using for measuring is the atan2(y,x) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2 formula. But I have 3 axis.. Does anyone know what formula is for 3d measuring in C code?

See below for my code:

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringPiI2C.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()

{

unsigned short int xl, yl, xh, yh, zh, zl;
short int x,y,z;    // size of a short is 2 bytes !!
int fd;
float declination = 1;
double angle;


fd=wiringPiI2CSetup(0x1E);
usleep(50000);  //delay 0,5 seconds


wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd, 0x00, 0x70);
wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd, 0x01, 0xA0);
wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd, 0x02, 0x01);

while(1)
{

    // start a new single measurement 
    wiringPiI2CWriteReg8(fd, 0x02, 0x01);
    usleep(50000);  //delay 0,5 seconds

    xh = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, 0x03); // x msb
    xl = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, 0x04); // x lsb
    zh = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, 0x05); // z msb
    zl = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, 0x06); // z lsb
    yh = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, 0x07); // y msb
    yl = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd, 0x08); // y lsb


    x = (xh << 8) | xl;
    y = (yh << 8) | yl;
    z = (zh << 8) | zl;

    angle = atan2((double)y, (double)x) + declination;
    if(angle > 2*pi) angle = angle - 2*M_PI;
    if(angle < 0) angle = angle + 2*M_PI;
    float heading_grade = angle * 180/M_PI;

    printf("\nAngle is: %f \n",heading_grade); 
    printf("X is: %d \n", x);
    printf("Y is: %d \n", y);
    printf("Z is: %d \n", z);

    usleep(50000); // delay 5 seconds  
}

return 0;


}
```

> The output I get is around +/-320 degrees when the sensor is
>   horizontal screwed down. The Y value stays the same, Z is changing
>   between -50 and +900 when I move the sensor and X is also changing
>   between -50 and +700 while moving.

Help would be very much appreciated, because I cannot get to figure it out.

Comment: Minor: Might as well use a better pi for `double` like `double pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;‬` or `double pi = acos(-1);`

Comment: Code has `float declination = 1;` is that suppose to be 1 degree or 1 radian?  Code is using a 1 radian (~57 degrees) and that is a large [declination](https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/what-declination?qt-news_science_products=0#qt-news_science_products).

Comment: @chux I found out that there was a function in de wiringPi.h library that's called M_PI, which stands for PI, so that's one thing I changed and the declination is indeed 1 degree in the Netherlands, so I guess that's also something I'm supposed to implement in the formula

Comment: Then consider `double angleD = atan2((double)y, (double)x) * 180/M_PI + declination;` and do `if(angleD > 360) ...`  Does using declination as a degree rather than radian provide good results?